# how to display my geolocation on my website for the public to see (live tracking)

Tags: iphone, html, gps, geolocation, real-time-updates

How can I show my geolocation on my website for the public to see?

For example, I want my friends to see my currently location (live tracking if i move) on my website. I would be using my mobile device to track myself. I've tried HTML5 geolocation on google maps, but that only display the location of the people who visit my site. Not mine current location.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use this if you're on an Android device:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.herverenault.selfhostedgpstracker

Just follow the instruction and your realtime location can be obtained in PHP.

> This small Android app sends your GPS coordinates to your server. It's your data, do what you want with it.

This is an application that sends your geolocation of your phone to the website, if it's requested. As you have the geolocation sent, you can do whatever you want (like embed it to Google Map or so).

But you have to understand there is a security concern if you want to share your location online.